# Null string returned from function but can print/echo inside function

Tags: php

I have a function inside a basic CMS that I'm writing:

```
protected function loadContent(){
    //Use the pages table
    $this->_dBase->table = 'pages';
    //Select Content
    $query = $this->_dBase->select('page_id, title, content', array('name' => get_class($this)));
    $html = $query[0]['content'];
    var_dump($html);
    return $html;
}
```

It gets called by my view method:

```
public function view(){
    $this->loadHeader();
    $this->loadNav();

    //Load possible methods
    //If false, loads main content
    if(!$this->loadMethod()){
        echo $this->loadContent();
    }
    $this->loadFooter();
}
```

The var_dump shows:

```
string '<div class="jumbotron">

         <h1>LiteCMS <small> a basic OOP PHP CMS</small></h1>

         <p>Manage the content of your Website with ease, using Twitter Bootstrap!</p>

         <p>

           <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="/about">Learn More &raquo;</a>

         </p>

       </div>' (length=301)
```

However, when I call the string to view(), it's Null.  I've tested this by trying to return a string of 'test', and it still returns Null.  I feel a little stupid, I haven't been able to reproduce this on a test page for printing a returned string value.  What am I missing here?

Thanks!

---

Update:
The error was occurring in an Inherited Class.  I was out of scope in the child class loadContent when I called the parent method loadContent. Derp.

Comment: Have you tested it without the `var_dump()` in the file?

Comment: Yes I have.  I've also called var_dump within the view method and it has returned null (without the var_dump in the loadContent method).

Comment: Disregard - I found the problem.  I was editing an inherited class and the output lost scope when it called the view method.